# How to subscribe content in community

Tags: community

Each content Page contains its own subscibe button

Please check below image

[image]

But in community doesn't contain "subscribe " Option.But it contains "following" Option.

[image]

**why subscribe Option isnt available in community users?**

**Any alternatives for community user to subscribe the contents** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Community Users to subscribe to a Content, you need to set the `View Content in Portals` permission on the community profile. Refer to the below screenshot from [View and Edit Content Subscriptions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=content_subscribe.htm&type=5) help documentation.

Also, remember that this feature is only supported in Classic, so if you are trying to view this in a Lightning Community, you may not be able to do so.

[image]

Comment: If I subscribed as partner user cant I view that content in community as a partner user??!!!

Comment: Don’t follow your question. As long as you were able to subscribe, that means that you were able to view it.

Comment: partner user not able tosubscribe in classic?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean by subscribing in Classic? Community Users with right permission will be able to subscribe from the Community.

Comment: As a community user I'am not able to subscribe content in classic

Comment: What do you mean by Classic here? Community Users don’t have (and can never have) access to *Internal Org* if that’s what you are referring to. They can access any content only through communities.

Comment: Ya.they wont ask internal org.You are saying that community user can access content in community. but they never get subscribe Option in community.In the profile level,if they have view content permission means they can view the contents. Please correct me If Iam wrong.

Comment: Have you set the permission? Also is your community built as a lightning community? Remember the feature is only supported in Classic or non Lightning community. Refer to the documentation for details.

Comment: In that document where they mentioned "View and Edit Content Subscriptions"??

Comment: Your question was on how to subscribe, the documentation clearly mentions that. Recommend you to go through it.